# Can I add a generic type to Swift's typealias?

Tags: swift, generics

I have this `typealias` for callback from network call.

```
typealias GenericReturn = ((Bool, Int, GenericModel)->Void);
```

But then I realized that sometimes I also need:

```
typealias UserReturn = ((Bool, Int, UserModel)->Void);
typealias PriceReturn = ((Bool, Int, PriceModel)->Void);
typealias ClientReturn = ((Bool, Int, ClientModel)->Void);
typealias ProductReturn = ((Bool, Int, ProductModel)->Void);
typealias CartReturn = ((Bool, Int, CartModel)->Void);
```

Can I simplify this `typealias` using some sort of generic syntax? Probably like:

```
typealias GenericReturn<T> = ((Bool, Int, T)->Void);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you have tested this? The compiler didn't complain in both Swift 3 & 4

Comment: it's working fine in playgroup with Swift 3. Did you try it?

Comment: Oh wait. It wasn't worked before. Now it works. I don't know what I tried last time that didn't work. I don't know that this even exist, so I probably was using some wrong syntax before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as a generic type alias

```
typealias MapResult<T> = (_ result: () throws -> T) -> Void
```

and use it in your code to map the network result like this:

```
func getSomeData(completion: @escaping MapResult<YourModel>) {
    let url = "Some Url"
    network.get(from: url) { (inner) in
        do {
            let result = try inner()
            let model: YourModel = try mapObject(result) 
            completion { return YourModel }
        } catch let error {
            completion { throw error}
        }
    }
}
```

and the mapObject based on the way you deserialise the result, I use [Marshal](https://github.com/utahiosmac/Marshal) will be like this:

```
func mapObject<T: Unmarshaling>(_ data: Data) throws -> T {
    return try T(object: try JSONParser.JSONObjectWithData(data))
}
```

and for mapping arrays:

```
func mapArray<T: Unmarshaling>(_ data: Data) throws -> [T] {
    return try JSONParser.JSONArrayWithData(data).map(T.init)
}
```

Comment: How to call the `getSomeData` function, with its completion example?

Comment: It's like calling a simple method with completion:

`getSomeData { (inner) in
            do {
                let result = try inner()
// you have the Model object here
                }
            } catch let error {
            }`